# Determining the number of red apples in a basket using opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, vision

I am trying to detect the number of red apples I have in a basket.
The samples are an empty basket, a basket with just one apple and a basket with two apples.

My approach to solve the problem is to find out when there is no apple in the basket ( by using the absence of red)

Plotting a histogram that shows when there is one apple in the basket.
I have no clue how to find out how n apples there are in a basket.

Comment: There will be more red pixels can be detected if there are two apples in a basket i guess.

Comment: A few example images would be helpful. I would try segmentation by color + findcontours and then count the number of connected components.

Comment: @WangYudong How can I measure the quantity using histograms?

Comment: @GilLevi I would like to use histograms to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is the apple and basket in your test image. You can calculate histogram of your samples using this **[OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a [LookUp Table](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table&ei=pgJpUpGBLvKO4gSMy4CgCw&usg=AFQjCNGSvcz6abUZTAGE8yd4bvkJxZXxVw&sig2=1_LnLWAGp5U_A2zmFLJ3bg&bvm=bv.55123115,d.eW0) if you are insisting on using histograms for this problem.
1. In this way you have to provide samples of histograms of images on every class that you are going to classify the images to (empty basket, a basket and one apple inside, a basket and two of them and so forth).
2. Using this sample you can create a unique criterion histogram for every class (the LUT), and a error function which can estimate how similar a histogram is to each of these criterion histograms (a simple error function can be the differences summation of the histogram value in every red intensity)
3. Whereby you can retrieve the error value of a histogram (of an input image) to each of LUT histograms and the one with minimum error is the class which your image belongs to.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here are some clues:

1. Convert your color to HSV space instead of on RGB space.
2. Count the pixels which you determined as "red" row by row (that's the way make the spatial histogram), find the location with the max number of red pixels.

If you are familiar with machine learning and computer vision, I would recommend Haar classification (similar way of face detecting).